# Javascript preload iframe without blocking the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, preload

I have several iframes to load with a huge 3D model behind.

When i display my iframe on my website, my browser block while this iframe is loading (maybe 20seconds..)

I'm looking for a way to preload these iframe without blocking the browser. I tried something with display none, ajax or by create iframe dynamically but no effect.

Do you have any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to preload iframe, unfortunately. I'd like to heard for any workaround too

Comment: not sure it'd make any difference, have you tried creating the iframes dynamically once the main page has loaded?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there is no clean supported/standard way of pre-loading iFrame without blocking the browser.

There are however ways you can minimize this "block". To give you some perspective, here's where the browser blocks:

- loading scripts
- loading big external resources (scripts/images/css/other media)
- heavy DOM manipulation
- intensive computation

**To mitigate script loading**, you can use techniques such as [Loading Scripts Without Blocking](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/). If you can get browser caching right, then the page in iFrame will spend no time downloading the script since its already in the cache.

**For other resources**, if applicable, you can use the same pre-loading techniques to fill up browser cache.

**Heavy DOM manipulation** - you can use techniques outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) and [here](http://blog.letitialew.com/post/30425074101/repaints-and-reflows-manipulating-the-dom) which will help you minimize repaints and reflows.

If possible, you can maybe adapt what ReactJs does, to minimize browser DOM manipulation by using a [virtual DOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#the-virtual-dom)

You mentioned 3D model computation and they tend to be computationally intensive. You should look at using [Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) which would offload the blocking aspect from the main browser thread into a background thread.

All of these techniques combined will minimize the block. You do not have to necessarily implement all of the techniques, if you can isolate and identify the part that's the biggest bottleneck.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load your `<iframe>` URLs in an AJAX GET request, then append them to the document once they are loaded.

I'd write something like the following:

```
var iframes = [{ location: "div1"; url: "url1.html" },{ location: "div2"; url: "url2.html" }];

iframes.forEach(function(current) {
  $.get(current.url).done(function() {
    $('#' + current.location).append('<iframe src="' + current.url + '"/>');
  });
});
```

Comment: Apart from the Cross-Origin conflicts: this does not preload iFrames as the content of an iFrame is not the same as the (X)HTML loaded by `src`.

Comment: @YoungRoger this solution works if it is not cross-domain, since the browser caches the AJAX response and the `<iframe>` will be loaded from the cache.

Comment: @dave Does it also preloads CSS/JS and/or images? Because it seems to me that it only caches the contents of the (X)HTML file. Not any additional resources specified inside that (X)HTML file, which is essential for preloading iFrames.

Comment: Well, no it doesn't preload the images and CSS. Depending on the complexity of the target iframe, you could traverse the DOM of the response and preload those resources as well.

Comment: This will do two requests: one for the AJAX request and one for the IFRAME.