# How to load an iframe without blocking onload or waiting for onload

Tags: javascript, html, performance, iframe

Suppose I have this page:

```
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<iframe src="https://example.com/test.html"></iframe>
```

And test.html contains this:

```
<img src="huge.png" />
```

`huge.png` is 100mb for some reason.

I have no control over test.html, but I must include the iframe in my page.

Is there a way to load the iframe without

1. blocking my page's `onload` event OR
2. waiting until my page's `onload` event to set the iframe's `src` attribute

I want #1 because I don't want JS on my page to have to wait for example.com's slow image.

I want #2 because I want to start loading example.com's content ASAP.

There are two similar questions.

- [is there a way to load an iframe asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114239/is-there-a-way-to-load-an-iframe-asynchronously)
- [Javascript preload iframe without blocking the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320816/javascript-preload-iframe-without-blocking-the-browser)

This is why they aren't duplicates:

1. Neither is clear what it means to "block" loading - I specify the `onload` event.
2. Neither specifies that I don't have control over the iframe's contents (which the first answer on #2 assumes).
3. Neither specifies that setting the `src` attribute after `onload` is not an option (which several answers on #1 assume).

While it's possible that answers to those questions *could* answer this one, neither is worded in such a way that the answer *must* answer this question.

Comment: I don't want to wait until the load event to start loading their content.

Comment: Then what is the higher level problem?

Comment: Their content blocking my page's onload event.

Comment: No way to do anything with a cross domain iframe. Could try using `DomContentLoaded` event instead

Comment: Ooh. Great interaction with existing questions, @MichaelCrenshaw!

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Window: DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) as suggested by [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583045/how-to-load-an-iframe-without-blocking-onload-or-waiting-for-onload/61372521#comment94029690_53583045) in the comments; it does not get blocked by resources/assets loading:

> The **DOMContentLoaded** event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and **subframes** to finish loading.

Here is a demo snippet that loads an external iFrame that has a 2MB JPEG image; when you run it, you'll see that `DOMContentLoaded` get to trigger before the iFrame fully loads and it runs custom Javascript; then when the iFrame is done loading, the `load` event on the iFrame is called and we update a status text.

```js
// On DOMContentLoaded set status text and start an ASCII animation
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('js-status').textContent = 'DOM fully loaded and parsed; staring JS code';

  const animation = new animascii({
      src: [
          ["0-----", "-----0"],
          ["-0----", "----0-"],
          ["--0---", "---0--"],
          ["---0--", "--0---"],
          ["----0-", "-0----"],
          ["-----0", "0-----"]
      ],
      display: document.getElementById("ascii-animation"),
      repeat: -1,
      delay: 120,
      font_size: 20
  }, function() {
      alert("Done!");
  });
});

// On iframe load event set status text
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('iframe-status').textContent = 'IFrame fully loaded';
});
```

```css
iframe { width: 600px; height: 400px; }
h2 span { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rot.js/0.6.0/rot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.cssscript.com/demo/ascii-animation-library-pure-javascript-animascii/animascii.js"></script>

<h2>DOM/JS status: <span id="js-status">(loading...)</span></h2>
<h2>IFrame status: <span id="iframe-status">(loading...)</span></h2>

<h3>Demo JS to check that JS is running after DOMContentLoaded and before iFrame finish loading</h3>
<div id="ascii-animation"></div>

<iframe src="https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/53583045/iframe.php"></iframe>
```

Of course you can set the iFrame `src` attribute on `load`, but that is already covered by the questions you're linking:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('js-status').textContent = 'DOM fully loaded and parsed; staring JS code';
  document.getElementById('iframe-status').textContent = '(loading...)';
  document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].setAttribute('src', 'https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/53583045/iframe.php');
});

document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('iframe-status').textContent = 'IFrame fully loaded';
});
```

```css
iframe { width: 600px; height: 400px; }
h2 span { color: blue; }
```

```html
<h2>DOM/JS status: <span id="js-status">(loading...)</span></h2>
<h2>IFrame status: <span id="iframe-status">(not started yet)</span></h2>

<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: Awesome demo, thanks! This would require moving my code that's currently firing on the `load` even to the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which (probably) comes significantly earlier, correct? I guess I should have added that my motivation was to push 3rd party tracking to load as late as possible (`load`) while also not having it be completely borked by a hung iframe. Promoting the 3rd party scripts to `DOMContentLoaded` isn't ideal. But might be the best available option.

Comment: I guess the "hung iframe" problem isn't unique to iframes. A third-party image or script could block the `load` event. iframes just tend to be particularly nasty. Maybe what I'm looking for is a synthetic event that fires when all scripts, images, and frames have loaded except <some list of elements>.

Comment: I'll probably try to build that synthetic event and add it as another answer. But barring some other magical solution appearing, I anticipate accepting this one. It's well-researched and -constructed. :-)

Comment: Thank you. Leave the bounty to the end so maybe there are other potential solutions. That's correct, `DOMContentLoaded` fires before the `load` event which fires when everything has been loaded; all big resources can block the `load` event because these have to be loaded before it fires. Where and when you'd dispatch that synthetic event? You can combine both `DOMContentLoaded` and the iFrame `load`, set flag variables for both and only if both flags are raised then dispatch that synthetic event for example.

Comment: Good plan. I'd fire the synthetic event when all elements _except_ the problem iframe finished loading (or some set of elements, based on a CSS selector). That way I could kick off the tracking scripts nice and late in the page load cycle and still not worry about the problem iframe. I took a crack at a solution here, but the script elements aren't firing a `load` event. :-/ https://jsfiddle.net/j4d1hLwf/

Answer (score 7):

In modern browsers all you need to do is add `loading="lazy"` to your iframe.

```
<iframe src="test.html" loading="lazy" />
```

It's [not supported everywhere](https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr), but maybe enough for your case?

Comment: If it starts loading before `load`, it won't block the event?

Comment: Just tested in Firefox 75, and it still blocks `load` if the iframe starts loading before `load`. I haven't tested what would happen if the iframe doesn't start loading until later, but with browser implementations of `loading` varying widely, I don't think this would be a viable solution for a while.

Answer (score 5):

A different and somewhat-easier trick: do the load as usual, but also include

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://example.com/test.html">
```

in your page's `<head>`.

The browser will [start fetching test.html (or huge.png) for you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ).

It doesn't even require the iframe to exist, you can put it in any page. If you want, you can have the browser start loading the external resource before it's even on the specific page that needs it.

The detailed time depends on the browser's decision, of course, but at the end of the day that's true for all async requests -- and you can put that `prefetch` first thing after the doctype stuff.

Comment: I do like this as a mitigation. My question was a little misleading, because I'm less concerned about an overweight iframe source than an iframe source that just hangs (due to an outage for example). But this would certainly help for the former case. Thanks!